# iOS Safari scroll to top does not work on certain pages. Why?

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, webkit, responsive-design

**Disclaimer: The site has meanwhile been updated, this issue does not occur anymore with the new version of the design.**

On a new site I built I noticed a weird quirk in Safari (iOS 5). Usually you can tap the black bar on top of Safari to scroll to the top of any webpage. On my new website this works on the homepage, but not on single article pages.

Try it! [versbeton.nl](http://versbeton.nl) (works!) vs. [versbeton.nl/2012/01/vers-vloeibaar/](http://versbeton.nl/2012/01/vers-vloeibaar/) (does not work!)

How can I debug such a situation? As far as I know there's no Firebug (or similar debugging tool) for iOS.

Comment: both links work fine on a iP4S with iOS 5.0.1. This behavior is common to all scroll views. Its malfunctioning shouldn't be tied to the content of the web view. Are you redefining any display properties of your web page ?

Comment: @teriiehina I actually found that the second link wouldn't scroll on an iPhone 4S with 5.0.1 or in the 5.0 iPhone simulator, as Florian reports. Though it was fine in the iPad 5.0 simulator. So presumably it's something about that Twitter/Facebook overlay that appears on the iPhone only?

Comment: @Tommy > just tried with the Simulator (my first comment, I was using my device) and it's still working. but I didn't see any twitter/facebook overlay (neither on device or simulator).

Comment: @teriiehina I guess that makes it even more likely to be the issue? It's a floating element right at the top of the page, so possibly Safari has some logic to disable the status bar if it decides accidental taps may be an issue? A capture from the simulator here, to show what I'm talking about: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/697/stscreen.png

Comment: @teriiehina the pages both display fine on my iPhone. The "scroll to top when the top black bar in Safari is tapped" does not work in the second link.

Comment: then I think @Tommy is right: the issue is certainly related to the SN overlay. Do you still have the problem if you disable it ?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists when I remove the Javascript that triggers "position: fixed". I'll do some more testing to find out when the expected behavior returns.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` is the problem. If you use that *anywhere* in your CSS, the scroll-to-top shortcut stops working. This is a known problem with iOS 5, there is no workaround unfortunately. Hopefully it will be fixed in iOS 6.

Comment: Awesome! Was there something published about this bug or did you stumble on it by chance?

Comment: Damn. And there's absolutely NO fix for this?

Comment: This is still an issue as of iOS 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You can have something similar to firebug buy using Safari and specifying your web-agent as iPhone. But I'm not sure you will have the same webkit engine.

You can also activate the Developers Tools for Safari in Settings > Safari > Advanced.

Good luck.

Comment: Using Safari on my Mac won't help me debug this iOS specific problem. There's no black bar that I can tap on my Mac... Or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: yes, there ain't no black bar on OSX but using the web dev tools of Safari can help you inspect the properties of your window and its elements. And you can still activate the Dev Tools on your iPhone.

Comment: Ah, "Debug Console" in iOS. That's a great tip! But alas: no errors that seem to have to do with this problem.