# JQuery scrollTo plugin becomes Jerky on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, scrollto, flicker

I'm using the JQuery [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/jqueryscrollto-142-released.html) on our [one-page site](http://www.designlagoon.com) to vertically scroll between the different sections.

The scroll works well in all browsers *except* iOS Safari which scrolls but is very jerky. I'm using a number of other Jquery plugins on the page so it may be a conflict with one of these.

If anyone knows an alternative to scrollTo that works smoothly on the iPad or can suggest where to start tackling the issue I'd appreciate the help. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4321140/725136) but without success.

Comment: you don't need a plugin for this. jQuery has .scrollTop since 1.2.6 http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ You can even animate using the animate method. Like .animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000, 'ease')

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970740/ios-safari-scroll-to-top-does-not-work-on-certain-pages-why

Comment: the scrollTo plugin still has many advanced features that vanilla core scrollTop does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tip Arnar.

Your advice put me on the right path and with the help of [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/) i now have exactly the [smooth scroll i wanted to achieve](http://www.designlagoon.es) with smooth animated scroll to each section and automatic highlighting of the active menu item.

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this one

```
$.scrollTo(SELECTOR, 800, {
    'axis':'y'
});
```

Comment: you saved me man! thanx! A 2 year old post and you posted a month ago, and I used this fix just now... coincidence? LOL