# iPhone Safari: how to intercept the scroll-to-top-of-page function on the clock

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

On iPhone Safari, when you tap on the clock in the black title bar, a web page normally scrolls to the top.

Does anyone know whether this generates a Javascript event that can be intercepted in order to provide custom functionality - and if so, which one? (The reason for asking is that I want to scroll the contents of an inner div while leaving a pair of header and footer divs unchanged.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970740/ios-safari-scroll-to-top-does-not-work-on-certain-pages-why The answer to this question seems like a quick and dirty hack to prevent this action. However, it may be changed in future versions of iOS.

Comment: Yep. The -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch property mentioned in that article is indeed in my code (actually, in the jqMobi library). I need the momentum scrolling facility, so it looks like I'll just be waiting for Apple to fix this one in iOS 7 - it's still broken in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not a js event but I saw some sites which deactivated the function somehow(but that's for sure not what apple intended with this function)